# OpenGL - crash after reorder rendering methods

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, glsl

As the title says, my problem is when I render one "object", especially terrain, and after the water grid, it goes well, but if I simply put the terrain render after water rendering, **it chrashes with this error:**

**Solved - bottom of the text.**

> *Unhandled exception at 0x55C3B970 (atioglxx.dll) in Pan3Da Engine.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.*

```
    void PNDHEIGHTMAP::p_renderwater()
{
    waterShader->bindShader();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,waterReflection.fbo_texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,waterRefraction.fbo_texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,waterGlobalReflection.fbo_texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE6);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,waterDepthBufferID);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,water_normal_map1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,water_normal_map2);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,water_dudv_map);

    waterShader->sendUniform("water_level",waterlevel);
    waterShader->sendUniform("reflection_texture",0);
    waterShader->sendUniform("reflection_global_texture",5);
    waterShader->sendUniform("water_depth_texture",6);
    waterShader->sendUniform("refraction_texture",1);
    waterShader->sendUniform("bump_map_1",2);
    waterShader->sendUniform("bump_map_2",3);
    waterShader->sendUniform("dudv_map",4);


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(waterVertArrayBuffer);
    for(unsigned long indRow=0;indRow<pndwater.indexRows;indRow++)
    {glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,pndwater.indexRange,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(void*)(sizeof(unsigned long)*pndwater.indexRange*indRow));}  <--------crash
};
```

this is my water rendering code, terrain is the same but with 2 VertexAttribArrays:(0) and (1), and less textures. The program crashes at the last line.

```
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_EXT);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glPolygonOffset(0.5f,0.5f);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    waterShader->bindShader();
    waterShader->sendUniform("light_position",pndskybox.light_position.x,pndskybox.light_position.y,pndskybox.light_position.z);
    waterShader->sendUniform("camera_position",camera.cameraPosition.x,camera.cameraPosition.y,camera.cameraPosition.z);
    waterShader->sendUniform("d_time",timer);
    pndheightmap.p_renderwater();
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glPolygonOffset(0,0);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_EXT);
```

I dont want to post all of the code cuz its pretty long. I render the water textures with fbo-s. Then bind water-shader and render the water with the method posted.

The same with my terrain:

```
terrainShader->bindShader();
terrainShader>sendUniform("light_position",pndskybox.light_position.x,pndskybox.light_position.y,pndskybox.light_position.z);
pndheightmap.p_rendermap_h();
```

My main rendering method looks like:

```
void PNDRENDER::render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    maprenderer.p_renderskybox();
    maprenderer.p_renderHeightMap();
    maprenderer.p_renderWater();
}
```

but if I change them:

```
....
maprenderer.p_renderWater();
maprenderer.p_renderHeightMap();
....
```

then it crashes. I really don't know what could possibly cause this problem, but it's annoying.
Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I can post more code if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've just found out what was the problem. Because I'm using VAO-s, I enabled vertex attributes in them, and i don't have to disable them. But I "reenabled" them before the draw call in void p_renderwater() and p_renderterrain(), so If I'm right it acted as it was globally enabled, not only within the scope of that VAO, but in the water VAO I only used 1 attrib, not two. If I put the terrain-render after the water it was OK, but if the terrain-method was the first, the water tried to accept the second attribute because I left that enabled globally.

Correct me if I'm wrong, or misunderstood something, but now it works well.